# Tensorboard Interactive Debugger Not Connecting

Tags: tensorflow, grpc, tensorboard

I am running the latest version of tensorflow (1.7.0) in Windows. It added a new feature for debugging in tensorboard. However, I am not able to get it to connect. I was previously using the LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession debugger. However, I wanted to play with the new features in TensorBoardDebugWrapperSession.

When I run tensorboard using the command "tensorboard --logdir=dir --debugger_port 6064" it tells me "Creating InteractiveDebuggerPlugin at port 6064".

However, when I run my model in tensorflow (after swapping out the LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession for the TensorBoardDebugWrapperSession) it never seems to connect to the interactive debugger. I don't get an error in the output for either tensorboard or tensorflow. Nothing happens and on the tensorboard debugger page it just shows: "Debugger is waiting for Session.run() connections..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `tensorflow` does not have support for grpc connection on `windows`. A workaround is to use windows subsystem. Note that there is no direct access to system `GPU` from the subsystem. So it cannot be use with tensorflow-gpu version

> > start_epoch: grpc:// debug URL scheme is not implemented on Windows yet.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17933